# How can I add drilldown in Highctock?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I would like to add an option of drilldown in Highstock, I tried with Highcharts and it works but i would like to use Highstock, Is it possible?

Comment: It should work. What kind of problems do you have? Highstock has the same core as Highcharts, so plugins between them should be compatible.